# searching for a working GWT RPC library

Tags: gwt, rpc

im searching for a GWT-RPC lib for the client side to communicate with a zend framework php server
thus rpc like json, xml or rest would be interesting

all i find are projects which have been stuck in years 2007/08 which dont seem to work anymore

so is there anyone who can suggest a working library?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know nobody has built a GWT-RPC to communicate with a non-Java server, to allow you to have the automatic object sharing between client (written in Java) and server (written in non-Java) that GWT-RPC provides.

Luckily, GWT provides a mechanism for communicating with a server in regular JSON, using [`RequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).  See [this link](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests) for more information about making regular HTTP requests in GWT.